# Pass input value to $mdDialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to pass a form input to my dialog (as title for example). The problem is: it don't get the form `$scope`.

If I set the `$scope` sinde the controller, it'll display normaly (see the `$scope.text` for example). But, if I try to get the form `$scope` (see `$scope.taskTitle) it just don't show anything. See my code:

**JavaScript**

```
app.controller('tasksCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdDialog',  function($scope, $mdDialog){


$scope.teste = 'Just a test, dude';

$scope.expandTask = function() {

    $mdDialog.show({
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        controller: DialogController,
        scope: $scope,
        preserveScope: true,
        templateUrl: 'models/dialog.tmpl.php',
        locals: {
            id: $scope.tasklist.id,
            title: $scope.taskTitle
        }
    });

}

function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog, id, title) {

    $scope.id = id;
    $scope.title = title;

    $scope.hide = function() {
        $mdDialog.hide();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $mdDialog.cancel();
      };
}
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-container float-icon" flex="100" layout="row" ng-repeat="task in tasklist">
    <md-input-container flex="100">
        <label>New Task...</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="taskTitle" name="taskTitle">
        <md-button aria-label="Expandir Tarefa" class="md-icon-button expand-icon" ng-click="expandTask()">
            <md-tooltip hide-sm>Expand Task</md-tooltip>
            <i class="fa fa-expand"></i>
        </md-button>
    </md-input-container>

    {{taskTitle}}

</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should pass in the `task` object from the ng-repeat into the ng-click.

For ex `ng-click="expandTask($event, task)"`

and in your $mdDialog controller, you will have access to that object:

```
app.controller('tasksCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdDialog', function ($scope, $mdDialog) {

    $scope.expandTask = function (e, task) {
        //ng-click="expandTask($event, task)"
        $mdDialog.show({
            clickOutsideToClose: true,
            controller: function ($mdDialog) {
                var vm = this;
                vm.task = {};
                vm.task = task;  //your task object from the ng-repeat

                $scope.hide = function () {
                    $mdDialog.hide();
                };
                $scope.cancel = function () {
                    $mdDialog.cancel();
                };
            },
            controllerAs: 'modal',
            templateUrl: 'models/dialog.tmpl.php',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: e
        });
    };
}]);
```

And in modal template you will access the task object with controllerAs notation, for example:

```
 <h1> {{ modal.task.name }} <h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Keep it minimal**

and create a controller with scope variables on the fly

```
$scope.expandTask = (e, task) =>
    $mdDialog.show({
        templateUrl: 'dialog.template.html',
        controller: $scope => $scope.taskName = task.name
    })
```

`taskName` is now a `$scope` variable and can be used in the dialog template