# Pass image to $mdDialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am attempting to pass an Ng-repeat to my `$mdDialog` but am not finding much documentation on how to do so. I have been referring to [This Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318748/pass-input-value-to-mddialog), but am having no luck on passing the image to the modal.

In the console I am getting an error saying:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined
```

What is the reason for the console error and not passing the image to the modal?

**HTML**

```
<md-grid-tile 
    ng-repeat="image in imageBucket.images"
    md-rowspan="{{image.row}}"
    md-rowspan-gt-lg="{{image.rowgtlg}}"
    md-colspan="{{image.col}}"
    md-colspan-gt-lg="{{image.colgtlg}}"
    class="white" >
    <md-button 
        class="" 
        ng-click="showAdvanced($event, image)" 
        flex="100" 
        flex-gt-md="auto">
        <img 
            aria-label="kpinsonstairs" 
            class="img-responsive md-whiteframe-6dp" 
            src="{{image.src}}" 
            alt="Gallery Picture">
            <md-grid-tile-footer>
                <h3>{{image.title}}</h3>
            </md-grid-tile-footer>
    </md-button>
</md-grid-tile>
```

**Javascript**

```
(function () {

  'use strict';

    angular
        .module('resonance.gallery.controllers')
        .controller('GalleryOneController', GalleryOneController);

    GalleryOneController.$inject = [
        '$scope',
        '$mdDialog',
        'ImageService'
    ];

    function GalleryOneController($scope, $mdDialog, ImageService) {

      ImageService.success(function(data) {
        $scope.imageBucket = data;
      });


      $scope.showAdvanced = function(ev, image) {

        $mdDialog.show({
          clickOutsideToClose:true,
          controller: function($mdDialog) {
            var vm = this;
            var image = {};
            var image = image;
            $scope.hide = function() {
              $mdDialog.hide();
            }
            $scope.cancel = function() {
              $mdDialog.cancel();
            };
          },
          controllerAs: 'modal',
          templateUrl: 'client/gallery/views/dialog.ng.html',
          parent: angular.element(document.body),
          targetEvent: ev
        });
      };
    }
})();
```

**Modal HTML**

```
<img 
     class="img-responsive md-whiteframe-6dp" 
     src="{{modal.image.src}}" 
     alt="Gallery Picture">
```

Comment: If you want to access the image in html, shouldn't it be vm.image = image??

Comment: @KarthikRP No, that does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you check at the documentation of [angular-material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog) , you will see that there is an option to resolve content to the controller of the modal by using the `locals` keyword .  So you will have to rewrite the function as :

```
$scope.showAdvanced = function(ev, image) {
    $mdDialog.show({
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        controller: function($mdDialog, image) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.image = image;
            $scope.hide = function() {
                $mdDialog.hide();
            };
            $scope.cancel = function() {
                $mdDialog.cancel();
            };
        },
        controllerAs: 'modal',
        templateUrl: 'client/gallery/views/dialog.ng.html',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        locals: {
            image: image
        }
    });
};
```

That should work .

Comment: Ok I tried that in my controller, but I am still not able to pass the image. I no longer have the console error which is a step forward. Another problem I have is my button for `cancel()` is not working. `clickOutsideToClose` is working though.

Comment: You are using the controllerAs way , So it is better to bind the methods and image variable to the controller (`this`)  . I will edit my answer , and in the html for the modal , have you added the required close buttons and its ng-click .

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly. Thank you. I will award the bounty as soon as it lets me :)